# MySQL Error 1064 : near NULL at line 1

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have been trying to figure out what am i doing wrong in the beloe procedure

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `example`(IN col_n char(50),IN p_cont char(50),IN p_ud int)
BEGIN

set @S = CONCAT('select rn.emp_id as     emp_id,controller,perma,permb,permc,permd,order from emp n
join resource_emp rn on rn.emp_id = n.emp_id 
join resource r on r.resource_id = rn.resource_id 
join u_resource ur on ur.resource_id = r.resource_id 
join user u on u.u_id =  ur.ur_id
join( 
select title,min(order) as pr from emp n
join resource_emp rn on rn.emp_id = n.emp_id 
join resource r on r.resource_id = rn.resource_id 
join u_resource ur on ur.resource_id = r.resource_id 
join user u on u.u_id =  ur.ur_id
where u.u_id = ',@p_ud,' group by title)a on a.title = n.title and a.pr = order
where u.u_id = ',@p_ud,' n.con = ''',@p_cont,''' and ,@col_n,' = 1
group by n.title order by n.order');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @S;

EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

I'm trying to execute the procedure as below but having the error

```
call hop_thlc_t.auth('perma', 'submit', 2);
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

while this happens, i can still execute the same and get desired results by running the above procedure as a query by using below params

```
 set @col_n ='perma';
 set @p_cont = 'submit' ;
 set @p_ud =2;
```

Any help to fix the issue is appreciated

Comment: You added @in front of all arguments, how about removing them?

Comment: hi, i see `@p_con` in your query while you are using `@p_cont` in the the argument list.

Comment: Typo, corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take the `@` off of your variables that are procedure arguments, as Sami Kuhmonen suggests in a comment.

Local variables in stored procedures don't have `@` before the name. If you use a variable like `@col_n` it's not the same variable as `col_n` which is the variable for your procedure argument.

Variables with `@` are called [Session Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). They have a scope outside your stored procedure. You discovered you can set the value before calling your procedure. Likewise, if you set the value of this variable inside the procedure, it will still have that value after your procedure returns.

I posted a demo in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41925146/20860

Unfortunately, there's an exception to every rule. When you use `PREPARE`, you *must* use a session variable. Local variables won't work for `PREPARE`.